# Goldbach's Conjecture in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

The conjecture:

> Every even number greater than $2$ is the sum of two primes.

$\forall a\in \Bbb N\left([(a=2b) \land (b>1)]\Rightarrow\left((2b=x+y)\land(\forall q\neq x(q>1 \land \lnot(q\vert x)))\land (\forall r\neq y (r>1 \land \lnot(r\vert y)))\; \right) \right)$

Does the statement in FOL above make sense?
Can it be simplified?

Comment: Why bother mentioning $a$? $\forall b\in\mathbb N[b\gt1\implies\dots]$ You're missing some existential quantifiers, e.g. $\exists x$.

Comment: Also, the part $(q > 1 \land \neg(q \vert x))$ should be $(q > 1 \to \neg(q \vert x))$ I think.